# $\lim_{x\to0} (\sin x-x)/x^3$ why can't the fraction be split first like $x/x^3 - \sin x/x^3$

Tags: limits, fake-proofs

$\lim_{x\to0} (\sin x-x)/x^3$ why can't the fraction be split first like $x/x^3 - \sin x/x^3$ and then later on be written as $1/x^2 -\sin x/x \cdot x^2$ and $\sin x/x =1$ so $1/x^2-1/x^2=0$

Comment: The split will  be successful provided the limits of splited partd are finite.

Comment: $\sin x/x \neq 1$

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you **can** do is split it up like

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$

However you **cannot** distribute the limit, i.e.

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\neq\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x^3}-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}.$$

The reason for this is because to do this, you need both the limits on the right hand side to exist, and clearly they do not (for one, $\frac{1}{x^2}\to\infty$ as $x\to0$). This is a general property of limits: you can only distribute the limit if the limits exist (and are finite of course), otherwise it might not hold. Take for example the limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}0=0.$$

If we would have instead distributed the limit first thing we did, then we would end up with something undefined as $\infty-\infty$, which is clearly nonsense. While this example is extremely contrived and trivial, it still shows the point, and a lot of the situations do end up occuring, which is why you have to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it simply doesn't work that way. You can write $$(\sin x-x)/x^3=\frac{(\sin x)/x}{x^2}-\frac1{x^2}$$if you like, but that doesn't help find the original limit, since the limits of the two terms on the right do not exist. Your argument *seems* to be saying that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac1{x^2}=\frac1{x^2},$$but that's not true. (Makes no sense; if that limit did exist it would be a single number, not a function of $x$...)

Good of you to add the "explanation" $\sin(x)/x=1$. That's not true, in fact it's easy to see that $|\sin(x)/x|<1$ for every $x\ne0$.

Comment: My "edit" was just a roll-back of a previous user's edit. All they did was replace your (more legible) fractions of the form $a/b$ to the less legible $\frac{a}{b}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3} = \frac{\frac{\sin x}x-1}{x^2}$$

You can't then simply say

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\frac{\sin x}x-1}{x^2} \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{x\to0} \frac {1-1}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac 0{x^2} = \lim_{x\to0} 0= 0$$

Although the numerator goes to $0$, so does the denominator. The numerator does not get to be zero without the denominator being zero. You can't pick and choose, letting $\frac{\sin x}x$ become $1$ first before $x^2$ becomes $0$. In fact, you don't know which one goes to $0$ faster, the numerator or the denominator, so you can't tell if it goes to $0$ or $\pm\infty$ or anything inbetween.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question. the question was why can't we rewrite it as $\sin(x)/x^3-x/x^3$.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing the following:
$$
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}=
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\stackrel{\text{$\ast$}}{=}
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}0=
0
$$

The problem is in the step marked by the $\ast$, all other steps are fine. Any step in math needs to be justified by a rule which is applied appropriately in the context of the expression. There is no rule for doing what is happening in step $\ast$. If even a single step cannot be justified, it might give you a faulty equality (which happens here) and all remaining steps, although correct when viewed in isolation, will in general produce unequal terms.

What you could do instead is to use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). Alternatively you could expand $\sin(x)-x=-\frac{x^3}{6}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ into a convergent power series and compute with that - this however might be beyond your level, as you need to interchange a limit and a series, which can be done here (theory of analytic functions which implies uniform convergence near $0$ for the function in question), but in general is wrong.

Your issues are in spirit similar to [this beginner struggling with limits](https://community.ptc.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/18925iB434E81389FCBE70/image-size/large?v=v2&px=999) or [that one](https://mathjokes4mathyfolks.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/limitsatinfinity.jpg).

Comment: "What you should do instead is to use L'Hôpital's rule." There are several ways of solving the problem, and most probably give more insight than the L'Hôpital route.

Comment: Replaced "should" by "could" in the spirit of Lorago's comment.